# Dual Number Generalization

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, complex-numbers

Is there any paper available that speaks about the generalization of the concept of Dual Number over a generic ring?
I cannot find anything.
I would like to be interested also in the generalization of the concept of Complex Number over a generic ring.
Is this problem already being challenged by someone?
The literature i think that is not complete, or maybe i cannot find the right answer.

Comment: I don't know references (the tag reference-request is especially designed for this type of question), but if $R$ is any ring, one can form the ring "$R[X] / X^2R[X]$" of "dual numbers over $R$" as well as $R[X] /(X^2 +1)R[X]$ that of "complex numbers over $R$". However, the latter will only be algebraically closed if $R$ is a field with some properties, and the former won't necessarly be a local field, which makes it less interesting. But I hope others will provide some interesting literature.